# What is the difference between ないでくれる and てくれない?

Tags: grammar, giving-and-receiving

> 「俺たちを見捨て**ねえでくれる**のはまあ、ありがたいですがね。……いくら俺たちが人獣だからって、手前**んとこや**親戚のチビどもとそう変わらねえガキが、むざむざ死んでくのを平気で見てられるほど残忍じゃありませんや。……気が変わったなら構わねえ、俺たちだけで行けって、命じてください」
>
> 86─エイティシックス─Ep.3 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈下〉 安里アサト

This question crossed my mind when I read this sentence. What is the difference between ないでくれる and てくれない? Could you illustrate the difference with some examples?

By the way, what does the んとこや mean here?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In ～ないでくれる *not* doing the verb is considered beneficial to the speaker, as your example illustrates (見捨てる is not generally a good thing), while in ～てくれない the verb itself would be a good thing but they're not doing it - like 「なんで一緒に行ってくれないの？」

If they're used in requests, also, ～ないでくれる？ is asking someone *not* to do something (「そんな目で見ないでくれる？」), whereas ～てくれない？ is just a politer way of phrasing ～てくれる？ (「お皿洗ってくれない？」)

If he had said 見捨ててくれねえ it would have confusingly sounded like he thought it would have been a good thing if they had, and then immediately contradicting himself.

Answer (score 0):

Another example that confuses learners is ～ないでいる. How is this different from ～ていない？

When you add ～ない and make a negative verb, you are actually making a new, independent word that means "to not ～". ～ないで is the te-form of that new verb.

You can rewrite the two like this:
「見捨てない」ことを「くれる」and 「見捨てる」ことを「くれない」